# Numpy to string over socket results in decoding errors

Tags: python, sockets, numpy, kivy

So for my school project i am using kivy to send images to an android phone, so far it went pretty well. but now i am stuck because the server side is sending an numpy array to the client but apparently kivy is not able to install numpy in python3, i tried this in python2.7 but i cant even get past another error about device capabilities. so my only solution left is to use numpy and turn this into an string so the texture of the kivy gui can display it. but so far i keep getting the error: "*this is an byte object and it does not have the tostring() method*" , and when i use tostring i keep getting "*invalid error code utf-8 cant decode.....*". Everything works fine on pc with numpy, i just need to do the client side without numpy but i cant seem to make it work.

Server side:

```
data = conn.recv(1024)

data = pickle.dumps(camera.get())  ### numpy frame

conn.sendall(struct.pack("!L", len(data)) + data)  ### new code
print("Test")
```

Client side:

```
data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("!L")
while True:

    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += self.s.recv(4096)

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]

    msg_size = struct.unpack("!L", packed_msg_size)[0]

    while len(data) < msg_size:

        data += self.s.recv(4096)

    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
```

Client side Buffer Texture Image:

```
image_texture = Texture.create(
size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')        
image_texture.blit_buffer(frame.flatten(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')    
self.texture = image_texture
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using frame.flatten() and then frame.tostring() before sending over socket.